# Determine the data type of the HTTP request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, http

I see that with `$.ajax()` I can use the `dataType` property to tell jQuery what kind of response I expect from the server, usually `json`.

But then on the server side, how do I know the data type that was requested?

I understand that normally the server should know what to send based on the content of the request, but my use case is a bit different here. I have an error handler built in PHP and I'd like to know in which format do I output the debug info. In case of fatal/syntax errors, warnings, the script may not even reach the request handler function associated with the request.

There's a `CONTENT_TYPE` header but apparently it's always `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and it's only sent on `POST` requests.

And there's a `HTTP_ACCEPT` header that looks like `application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`. Do I need to parse this string?

Comment: It's probably a better idea to have a separate query parameter that indicates what type of response you should send. I don't think you should depend on `HTTP_ACCEPT` being set correctly, and someone might ask for e.g. plain text but then want to parse it as JSON later.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way for client to tell server what data type is wanted. Clients do not tell "I want text/plain" or "only HTML please" (this can only be *assumed* from the URI). They only tell what they can potentially interpret (`HTTP_ACCEPT`) and what they post (`CONTENT_TYPE`).

For your server side error handler to reliably determine which output format to use, you could pass additional request headers or query parameters with your request, for example:

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    headers: {
        "X-Expected-Format": "text/plain"
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: The [`Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) request header does just that. If this only contained `text/plain` then the client _is_ telling the server what data type is wanted. The server should respond with a `HTTP 406` if it cannot return that data type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard convention for the Ajax client to tell the server what data format it wants in the response.

Usually one of several things is true for a specific Ajax request.

1. The request is known to generate a specific type of response (e.g. this response only and always generates JSON).  The client doesn't request a specific type of data.  It just knows that this particular request only returns JSON.
2. The request has a specific argument sent with it that the client uses to request a specific type of returned data (e.g. XML, HTML, JSON, etc...).  This may be a query parameter (if it's a GET request).
3. The path of the Ajax call determines the type of response requested.  For example, I've seen an API that uses one of the path segments in the request to determine whether the response should be XML or JSON.

Though option 2 could be done with a custom HTTP header, usually this is not done with HTTP headers.  If any argument is sent, it is usually sent as part of the ajax call arguments (however they are sent).

---

The `dataType` option that jQuery offers is to tell the jQuery library exactly what type of response it should expect so that if it is JSON, for example, it can parse the JSON for you.  This argument is not normally needed because jQuery can usually tell what type the response it based on the HTTP headers or based on a sample of the response itself.  There is certainly no harm in specifying the `dataType` for the Ajax request, but it absolutely must match the type of data that the server returns and the `dataType` value you set is not sent to the server in any way.  This is purely an instruction to the client-side library for how it should process the response when it arrives.